# Passar valor de uma função para value no input em JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tenho um input onde a pessoa deve digitar a data de nascimento, quando ela digita, automaticamente já chama uma função que faz o cálculo da idade. Após isso gostaria que o valor da idade fosse passado automaticamente para value do input abaixo da data de nascimento, porém não estou conseguindo.

```
//input recebe a data de nascimento
<input class="form-control fc-datepicker" placeholder="DD/MM/AAAA" type="text" id="data_nascimento" onblur="calcularIdade(this.value);">

//calcula a idade  
    <script type = "text/javascript" >
      function calcularIdade(aniversario) {
        var nascimento = aniversario.split("/");
        var dataNascimento = new Date(parseInt(nascimento[2], 10),
          parseInt(nascimento[1], 10) - 1,
          parseInt(nascimento[0], 10));

        var diferenca = Date.now() - dataNascimento.getTime();
        var idade = new Date(diferenca);

        return alert(Math.abs(idade.getUTCFullYear() - 1970));

    </script>

//input que recebe a idade
    <input class="form-control fc-datepicker" value="" disabled type="text" id="idade">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta pegar o input pelo id e alterar seu value:

```
document.getElementById("idade").value = Math.abs(idade.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
```

Só que você tem que fazer isso antes do `return` e após a variável `idade`.